# WPF listbox with images inreasing memory

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I am using listbox of images its increasing the memory usage upto giga bytes.I am using this xaml.

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <ListBox   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FilterImportSlideCollection}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource slideItemTemplate}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
```

And the template is

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="slideItemTemplate" >
    <Grid Width="100" Height="130"  Margin="2 2 2 2" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="0" Panel.ZIndex="3" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Right="0">
            <Image MinWidth="100" MinHeight="80" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding ImagePath, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"></Image>
            </Border>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="Black"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

each ImagePath has the path of images like 
"https://localhost:2673/SlideThumbnail/1272.png"

Comment: First of first, put your Images in local folder.

Comment: It may work on first attempt,but if i open the list box multiple time after adding some images images on server i will need to re download all the images again in local directory.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't work.

Comment: how many list items are we talking about?

Comment: around 200 and more

Answer (score 1):

Placing the `ListBox` inside a `ScrollViewer` disables **UI Virtualization** meaning all your `ListItems` are created in memory at once.

try:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FilterImportSlideCollection}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource slideItemTemplate}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
</Grid>
```

For further information about virtualization have a look at MSDN:

[Displaying Large Data Sets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879(v=vs.110).aspx#Displaying)